# Java Mission Control Listener?

Tags: java, performance, profiling, jfr, java-mission-control

I currently have some Java code that I would like to profile. I decided to use Java Mission Control after reading some promising things about it. However, every resource I've consulted so far tells me to first start the process I want to profile first, and only then "attach" or profile the code from Mission Control once it is already running (for example this video from oracle: https://youtu.be/WMEpRUgp9Y4?t=14m56s).

Is there a way to start the process with profiling from the start? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to start a profiling recording when you start the process.

Example: Running a profiling recording for 10 minutes.

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=10m,name=Test,filename=recording.jfr,settings=profile -jar target/highcpu-0.0.1.jar
```

See my article for more details: [Using Java Flight Recorder](https://medium.com/@chrishantha/using-java-flight-recorder-2367c01deacf#.w8lh5qkwp)

Answer (score 0):

It's not very well documented but there is the possibility.
You need to use this jvm options

-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=

The first two are mandatory while the last one need to be configured with various parameters that you can find explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm#BABIECII). 
It's not straightforward to understand the meaning of each parameter but with some trial and error you can find a good set of option pretty easily.

Just as reference this one is a minimal functional configuration:

```
java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,repository=/tmp,maxage=6h,settings=default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

JDK 11:

```
-XX:StartFlightRecording
```

JDK 9, JDK 10:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:StartFlightRecording
```

JDK 8u40,

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:StartFlightRecording=name=whatever
```

JDK 7u4, JDK 8u20:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures 
-XX:+FlightRecorder 
-XX:StartFlightRecording=name=whatever
```

If you want to avoid attaching to the process all together,  you can specify a filename, i.e -XX:StartFlightRecording=filename=rec.jfr, and then either dump the recording after a period by setting a duration, i.e. duration=60s, or if you only want it to happen when the JVM exits:

```
 -XX:StartFlightRecording=
 filename=rec.jfr,dumponexit=true
```

You can the open then open recording file in JMC. In JDK 11, this has been simplified further so you only need to specify:

```
 -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=c:\recs
```

and the filename will be generated in the specified directory and it will automatically dump when the JVM exits.